# Orchard CMS - Grouping fields

Tags: orchardcms

Is there a possibility to have fields that are added to a contentpart to be grouped. I don't know upfront what fields the customer will add. And if he adds a lot of fields to the contentpart, it would be nice if there was some kind of identifier to group them. 
Should I take over the Orchard.Fields module and modify it or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that today, but this is such a common request that I think it should be submitted as a work item (or even better, a patch) on CodePlex. We should add a group attribute to fields and maybe even parts.

UPDATE: I created it for you: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18920 Feel free to vote for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just have voted for it. I will keep the question as unanswered for now.